# Specifying a directory when using PHP use statement?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm working on an old Laravel project and in the api.php routes file, there is code like the following.

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use App\Http\Controllers\VendorApi;

Route::get('/some-route', [Api\SomeController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/some-vendor-route', [VendorApi\SomeController::class, 'index']);
```

The directory for the controllers is:

```
app/
├─ Http/
│  ├─ Controllers/
│  │  ├─ Api/
│  │  │  ├─ SomeController.php
│  │  ├─ VendorApi/
│  │  │  ├─ SomeController.php
```

This is throwing all kinds of errors when I run `php artisan route:list` even though the code is working still. Errors like this.

> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Api\App\Http\Controllers\Api\SomeController] does not exist.

> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Api\App\Http\Controllers\VendorApi\SomeController] does not exist.

I've tried to look up if specifying a directory when using the `use` statement is valid PHP, but I can't find any info in regards to it. ChatGPT says that it is not valid.

Does anyone know if specifying a directory when using the `use` statement in PHP is valid?

Comment: Since they have the same name, I would suggest not using the `use` statement and just using the full namespace on each route. If they have different names, take out the `Api`/`VendorApi` out of the route

Comment: The `use` statement is merely for aliasing *names*. It makes it so you can write `Api\SomeController` in your code instead of `App\Http\Controllers\Api\SomeController` everywhere. That's literally it. `use` doesn't look up any directories or imports anything. You still need to `require`/`include` the file that contains the class somewhere, which in such frameworks usually happens with an autoloader. It's the autoloader that's incorrectly looking up the class.

Comment: The answer to your question "*Does anyone know if specifying a directory when using the use statement in PHP is valid?*" is "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have defined a namespace on the route group that is loading your `api.php` route file. Go to your `RouteServiceProvider` and see if the group that is loading that file has a namespace defined.

Otherwise, it could be a namespace defined on the `RouteServiceProvider` itself.